# push associative array error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to push elements in an associative array from another array after some processing and I'm doing something  this:

```
for(var i in this.aNames) {
    var a = this.aNames[i];
    // some processing on a
    aList[i] = a;
    aList.push(i);
}
```

But it's not giving me the proper array.

EDIT :

Here `aNames` is an associative array like this

```
'1232':'asdasdasd',
'6578':'dasdasdas' 
...... and so on of about 100 elements.
```

I'm using `for` here as I want to do some changes in every element of the array.

Then I'm displaying the result array on the page but it's showing the key value together with the array data.

I.e. it should only display `asdasdasd` or `asdasdasd` but it's displaying keys too, like `1232 asdasdasd 6578 dasdasdas`.

Comment: We could guess what what is wrong, but I'm not going to bother. If it isn't giving you "the proper array", what is it giving you? Are any error messages being reported? What is `this`? What is `aNames`? Why are you using `for in` without `hasOwnProperty`? What is `d`? What is `aList`?

Comment: have editied my question

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things which may go wrong...

Primarily, make sure that `this` is pointing to the correct context and that `this.aNames` is actually returning a complex object (associative array).

Also, what's `aList`?  Is it an array?  If it is, `push` should append your array with the key of the current member (the member's name).

If you want to append the values of the members on your source object, you need to do something like this:

```
var obj = {name: 'dreas'},
    arr = []; // arr is an array

arr.push(obj["name"]); // arr now contains a single element, 'dreas'
```

In your `for..in` construct, you are both adding elements to an alleged array (`aList`) with `push` but also creating new members on your array (with the subscript notation, aList[i] = "asd" since i in this case (for..in iteration) refers to the member's name).

So, what you need to do is **decide if you want to *add elements to an array* or *members to an object*, not both.**

If you just want to clone an array, use a `for loop`.  If on the other hand you want to clone an object, it's not that trivial because members can also be complex objects containing their own members, and simply doing `arr[i] = obj.member` will only copy a pointer to `arr[i]` if `member` is a complext object, not a value type.

---

Just to make sure my terminology is understandable:

```
var anObject = {name: "dreas"},
    anArray = [1,2,3];

    anObject["name"] <= member (results in "dreas")
    anArray[1]       <= element (results in 2)
```